# How do i refresh my Twitter API every 15 seconds?

Tags: jquery, api, twitter, refresh, intervals

I was successful in installing the TWITTER API jquery script, but I can't figure out how to make the script refresh with the latest tweets without refreshing the entire page IN 15 SECOND INTERVALS.  Is it possible to use a .load or refreshID to reload script?  Can I also include a fade in and fade out when the function reloads?

Anyone done this?

Many thanks.

Erik

Here is my script:

```
<script src="/src/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery/jquery.jtwitter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get latest 6 tweets by jQueryHowto
    $.jTwitter('eriksnet', 3, function(data){
        $('#posts').empty();
        $.each(data, function(i, post){
        $('#posts').append(
            '<div class="post">'
            +' <div class="txt">'
            // See output-demo.js file for details
            +    post.text
            +' </div>'
            +'</div>'
        );
    });
});
});
</script>



<div id="posts">Getting Erik's tweets...</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into a jquery plugin $.doTimeout, it makes this pretty trivial.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get latest 6 tweets by jQueryHowto
    $.doTimeout(15000, function() {
        $.jTwitter('eriksnet', 3, function(data){
            $('#posts').empty();
            $.each(data, function(i, post){
                $('#posts').append(
                    '<div class="post">'
                    +' <div class="txt">'
                    // See output-demo.js file for details
                    +    post.text
                    +' </div>'
                    +'</div>'
                );
            });
        });
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

Just make sure that you include the dotimeout js file in your code.

Comment: I read your reference link, but I'm not sure how to call the function of the Twitter API.  Could you offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your jTwitter call in a function and calling it via setInterval

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

(about half way down the page)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to create an `interval` so that your application polls every 15 seconds. Mozilla's developer center [has an article on the basics of using setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) that will get you started.

Basically, you'll do something like this:

```
var f = function(){
    $.jTwitter('[user]',6,function(data){
        $('#posts').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            // build your html
            $(this).append(yourHtml).fadeIn();
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(function(){ setInterval(f,15000); });
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly.



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var f = function(){
    $.jTwitter('eriksnet',3, function(data){
        $('#posts').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $.each(data, function(i, post){
            $(this).append(
                '<div class="post">'
                +' <div class="txt">'
                
                +    post.text
                +' </div>'
                +'</div>'
            ).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){ setInterval(f,1000); });
</script>